# apk size increases when I use the ffmpeg library

Tags: android

Previously I used ffempg library for video compression in Android. But my apk size increased to 25 Mb.
Please help me find any alternative way for compressing video.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your APK size was increased because ffmpeg binaries was put inside the APK.

For Android version 4.3 (API 18) and newer you can use [MediaCodec API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html). It was introduced in API 16 but expanded functionality is available since API 18 (e.g. [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class).

To understand how it works I recommend you go through Android's unit tests [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java) and [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).